# Anchor tag click is not working in a form, if the form input field has focus and has validation errors

Tags: angularjs

```
<body ng-app="debounceExample">
  <div ng-controller="ExampleController">
  <form name="form" ng-submit="go()" novalidate>
    <label>Name:</label>
    <input name="input" type="text" required ng-model="user"  /><br />
     <div  ng-messages="form.input.$error" ng-show="form.input.$touched">
           <div  ng-message="required">required</div>
     </div>

    <a href="" ng-click="go()">test</a>
  </form>
</div>
</body>
```

Please focus input field and click on anchor tag. You can see, the anchor tag click is not working as the input field validation is triggered on blur. I am seeing the issue is due to using form.input.$touched in ng-show. I have created a plunker to reproduce the issue.

http://plnkr.co/edit/0NMhxP18EhBjLyKrJQV5?p=preview

To reproduce the issue, first focus input field and then click on anchor tag.

Comment: You question is unclear please elaborate.

Answer (score 1):

If you change the `ng-show` to

```
ng-show="!form.input.$pristine"
```

You may get the behaviour that you want.
Here is an updated [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/g734VL?p=preview).

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the href='' from your anchor tag.  It's also working fine even in your plunkr so I'm not sure what is the actual problem. A form has its own scope, so if you try something like

```
<a ng-click='myVar = !myVar'>click me</a>
```

and you set myVar=false outside the form it won't work.  You would need $parent.myVar, but that isn't the case here.